# Cannot access this.state or this.props outside the .then(json) fetch call unless i wrap console.log(this.state) inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch

I cannot access `this.state` or `this.props` outside the `.then(json)`. If i try to do `console.log(this.state, this.props)`, 
I see the state and props inside the log, but once i click on it, both arrays are empty. However, if i wrap the `console.log` around a `setTimeout()`, it works. However, this creates a scoping issue for me, because i need to inject the state from this component as props into the `FeedTable` component like so ---

`<FeedTable fetch_call={this.state.quakes_list} />`

The problematic `console.log` is `console.log('QUAKES LIST COMPONENT STATE ', this.state.quakes_list);`

Once i move it below the following `})`, it renders an empty `[]`

any help would be much appreciated! Here is the full code for the component:

```
class QuakeFeed extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            current_quakes: [],
            quakes_list: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        // USE CURRENT TIME TO FETCH LIVE DATA
        // GET DATE AND TIME TODAY
        let time_now = new Date().getTime();
        let date_now = new Date(time_now);
        let data_now = date_now.toString();     

        // SPLIT THE DATE TO EXTRACT TO 'YEAR-MONTH-DAY' FORMAT
        let split_date = data_now.split(' ');

        // SEGREGATE MONTH AND RETURN NUMBER INSTEAD OF MONTH       
        let date_arr = split_date.slice(1,4);

        // SHUFFLE ARRAY TO PROPER FORMAT           
        let year  = date_arr[2];
        let month = date_arr[0];
        let day   = date_arr[1];

        // IF MONTH STRING, PARSE TO NUMERIC
          month === 'Dec' ? month = '12' 
        : month === 'Nov' ? month = '11' 
        : month === 'Oct' ? month = '10' 
        : month === 'Sep' ? month = '09' 
        : month === 'Aug' ? month = '08' 
        : month === 'Jul' ? month = '07'
        : month === 'Jun' ? month = '06' 
        : month === 'May' ? month = '05' 
        : month === 'Apr' ? month = '04' 
        : month === 'Mar' ? month = '03' 
        : month === 'Feb' ? month = '02' 
        : month === 'Jan' ? month = '01' 
        : null;

        // TODAY USING MODIFIED YEAR, MONTH, DATE
        const today = [year, month, day]
        let yesterday = day - 1;        
        yesterday.toString();

        // FETCH CALL TO GET DATA (ARROW FUNCTION TO BIND TO PARENT SCOPE)
        const repeat_fetch = () => {

            // ----------------- INITIAL FETCH -----------------
                // USE THE VARIABLES TO PLUG IN YEAR, MONTH, DAY AND INITIATE FETCH CALL
                fetch ('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=' + year + '-' + month + '-' + yesterday + 
                       '&endtime=' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day + '&minmagnitude=5')

                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })

                .then((json) => {       

                    let eq_props = json.features;

                    store.dispatch({ type: 'FETCH-RESPONSE', payload: eq_props })

                    // EARTHQUAKE DATA FROM FETCH 
                    let fetched_req = store.getState();

                    // SET COMPONENT STATE TO STATE FROM REDUX STORE
                    this.setState({current_quakes: fetched_req});                   

                    // LOG CURRENT EARTHQUAKES
                    // console.log('Data', this.state.current_quakes);

                    // CURRENT EARTHQUAKES
                    const quakes = [].slice.call(this.state.current_quakes.quake_data);

                    // STORE QUAKES IN OBJECT TO PACKAGE AND PUSH INTO REDUX STORE
                    let quake_table_data = {};                  

                    for (var i = 0; i < quakes[0].length; i++) {

                        // LOCATION, MAGNITUDE, TIME OF CURRENT EARTHQUAKES
                        const quake_location = quakes[0][i].properties.place;
                        const quake_mag      = quakes[0][i].properties.mag;
                        const quake_time     = new Date(quakes[0][i].properties.time).toLocaleString();

                        quake_table_data.loc = quake_location;
                        quake_table_data.mg  = quake_mag;
                        quake_table_data.tim = quake_time;                      

                        /* 
                            PUSHES THIS OBJECT TO THE REDUX STORE SO THAT YOU CAN ACCESS IT INSIDE 
                            THE FEED TABLE COMPONENT AND CREATE A DYNAMIC TABLE 
                        */
                        store.dispatch({ type: 'STORE-QUAKES', payload: quake_table_data });
                    } // END LOOP                   

                    // GET PROPS FROM mapStateToProps OF REDUX STATE AND SET STATE                  
                    this.setState({ quakes_list: this.props.e_quakes[0]});
                    console.log('QUAKES LIST COMPONENT STATE ', this.state.quakes_list);
                })

            // -------------------------------------------------

            setTimeout(function() {
                // USE THE VARIABLES TO PLUG IN YEAR, MONTH, DAY AND INITIATE FETCH CALL
                fetch ('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=' + year + '-' + month + '-' + yesterday + 
                       '&endtime=' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day + '&minmagnitude=5')

                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })

                .then((json) => {                               
                    repeat_fetch();     
                })
            }, 330000);

        } // END repeat_fetch()

        repeat_fetch();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='section-quake-feed'>

                <FeedTable fetch_call={this.state.quakes_list} />

            </div>
        )
    }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            e_quakes: state.quake_data
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(QuakeFeed);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `quakes_list` is an empty array when you log it outside the `.then` is that the asynchronous call hasn't returned yet when you call `console.log`. The order of operations is:

1. Call `fetch` (code in `.then` doesn't start until the response comes back)
2. Call `console.log` (because this is the next synchronous command), which logs the empty array you initialized in `this.state`
3. Response comes back from `fetch` and `quakes_list` data is set in state

Hopefully that answers your question... my guess is that you're also having an issue getting `<FeedTable>` to render `quakes_list` because it's not set in state when `render` is called. If that's the case, a common solution is to check the property in state, and return a loader if it doesn't exist:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='section-quake-feed'>
      {this.state.quakes_list.length ? (
        <FeedTable fetch_call={this.state.quakes_list} />
      ) : (
        "Loading..." // Or some fallback Loader component, or `null`
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What happens is: `render` is called and returns the fallback because `quakes_list.length` is 0, then when `quakes_list` is set, `setState` causes a re-render and the FeedTable component is rendered.

Comment: This worked, but how can I avoid this situation beforehand in the future?

Comment: Glad it helped! Gaining a deeper understanding the order of execution when you use promises will help avoid this in the future. Dealing with asynchronous code can be confusing, and promises can make it easier, but only if you have an understanding of what happens when. As soon as you call a function that returns a promise (like `fetch`), any synchronous code that happens OUTSIDE of a `.then` will not wait for the `.then` to complete.